# Errors using signpost api for oauth in java

Tags: java, api, oauth

I have been trying for months to get access to a certain api (which has almost no documentation) to work using signpost. The api has oauth 2.0 authentication. The problem is that I have never used oauth before. But I have spent a long time reseaching so I think I have a functional understanding of how it works. I thought that using the handy singpost api it wouldn't be too much trouble to hack through it, but alas I have encountered a wall. The api docs are here:
https://btcjam.com/faq/api
It gives three URLs that are needed for the oauth authentication, which I am writing as java here for consistency with some code below:

```
String Authorization=   "https://btcjam.com/oauth/authorize";
String Token    ="https://btcjam.com/oauth/token";
String Applications =   "https://btcjam.com/oauth/applications";
```

I have an application with a name, key, and secret. I also have set my callback URL to be the localhost, i.e.

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/btcjam/callback.
```

Now, as I am reading the signpost docs, it tells me that in order to request an access token, I need to do something like the following:

```
OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
            REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL,
            AUTHORIZE_WEBSITE_URL);
String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
```

However, I am unsure exactly what to put for the URL's in these various spots, and I am getting errors. The problem is that The names of the URLs required above do not correspond to the URLs given. The "authorization" and "callback" URLs seem to match up nicely, but I am not sure how the URLs "REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL" and "ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL" required in the signpost docs correspond to the URLs given by the api docs on the serverI am trying to access. Of course, there are only two possible permutations, but when I try them both I get two different errors:

"Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match."

"Communication with the service provider failed: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: " 1""

Could someone please help explain what might be going on here? Am I very close to getting this to work or do I have to take a bunch of steps back?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul